How to add the evey objects to Many-to-Many relationship model
class MyUserGroup(BaseModel):
    my_user_types = m.ManyToManyField('MyUserType',blank=True)

I have this models which has the many-to-many relation ship to type.
Now I want to give the every MyUserType objects to this model such as
muy = MyUserType()
muy.save()
muy.my_user_types.add(MyUserType.objects.all())

However this shows the error like this,
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <SafeDeleteQueryset [<MyUserType:A>, <MyUserType: B>, <MyUserType: C>]>.

How can I make this?

try this:
mg = MyUserGroup()
mg.save()
queryset = MyUserType.objects.all()
mg.my_user_types.add(*queryset)

mt = MyUserType()
mt.save()
queryset = MyUserGroup.objects.all()
mt.myusergroup_set.add(*queryset)

